# Поменять местами value в Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый день как можно поменять местами скриптом value="2">П2 и value="5">П5.

HTML

```
<select id="inbound_from" name="blockger2016.inbound_from" onchange="mzchange()" style="display: block;">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="">От кого</option>   
<option value="1">П1</option>
<option value="2">П2</option>
<option value="3">П3 </option>
<option value="4">П4 </option>
<option value="5">П5 </option>
</select>
```

Хотелось бы видеть так
HTML

```
<select id="inbound_from" name="blockger2016.inbound_from" onchange="mzchange()" style="display: block;">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="">От кого</option>   
<option value="1">П1</option>
<option value="5">П5</option>
<option value="3">П3 </option>
<option value="4">П4 </option>
<option value="2">П2 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Вопрос: зачем? И еще вопрос: на стадии формирования списка нельзя это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без jQuery:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('inbound_from');
var option = select.querySelectorAll('option');

viceVersa( option[2], option[5] );

function viceVersa(a, b){
  helper = document.createElement( b.tagName );
  // не div, потому что плохо знаю HTML - вдруг есть теги, где браузер не принимает div
  b.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', helper); // .after(...);
  
  a.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', b);
  helper.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', a);

  helper.parentNode.removeChild(helper); // .remove();
}

setInterval( function(){ viceVersa( option[2], option[5] ); }, 1000 ); // ненужное демо
```

```html
<select id="inbound_from" size="6">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="">От кого</option>
  <option value="1">П1</option>
  <option value="2">П2</option>
  <option value="3">П3 </option>
  <option value="4">П4 </option>
  <option value="5">П5 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант c jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.swap = function(b) {
    b = jQuery(b)[0];
    var a = this[0],
        a2 = a.cloneNode(true),
        b2 = b.cloneNode(true),
        stack = this;

    a.parentNode.replaceChild(b2, a);
    b.parentNode.replaceChild(a2, b);

    stack[0] = a2;
    return this.pushStack( stack );
};

 $("option:nth-child(3)").swap("option:nth-child(6)");
```

Comment: Можно по подробнее

Comment: "как можно поменять местами скриптом value="2">П2 и value="5">П5". какой вопрос такой ответ, подробней некуда. Либо подробней описывай задание.